# What does <*> do in addRecip x y = fmap (+) (recipMay x) <*> recipMay y?

Tags: haskell, applicative

```
addRecip :: Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
addRecip x y = fmap (+) (recipMay x) <*> recipMay y
  where
    recipMay a | a == 0 = Nothing
               | otherwise = Just (1 / a)
```

I look up some explanation for `<*>`.

`<*>` takes a functor that contains a function taking an `a` and returning a `b`, and a functor that contains an a, and it returns a functor that contains `a` `b`. So `<*>` kind of extract the function from a functor and applies it to an arguments also inside a functor, and finally returns the result into a functor

This is an example:

```
fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```

But in my case, it seems a bit different. The elements in `recipMay x` are not functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<*> Applies an applicative value to another. It's a richer counterpart to regular function application. The applicative values are decorated in some way, for example, it can be optional whether there's any value as you would perceive it (for Maybe, which is your case), or there can be very many values (for List).

The application of one applicative value to the other therefore has some special behaviour. For lists, a <*> b applies each member of a to each member of b making a huge list of all combinations whilst for Maybe (which is your case) a <*> b gives Just (a' b') if a and b are (Just a') and (Just b') and gives Nothing if either or both a and b are Nothing - for Maybe, in summary, it's function application for optional values where the result is absent if any value involved is absent.

There are some rules to how <*> is implemented which means that you can always view this as [apply a "contained function" to a "contained value"] and as long as you do all your work in the contained domain (using <$>, <*>, pure, >>=, <|>, etc) then you can think of it as the same as regular function application, but when you come to "extract" values you get to see the added richness.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) comes from the `Applicative` typeclass. An `Applicative` is a (quoting the documentation) "*A functor with application.*". You can think of a `Functor` as a collection (although there are other types that are no collections that are functors, like a function for example).

If we see a functor as a collection then the `(<*>)` operator thus takes two of these collections. The first collection stores functions of type `a -> b`, and the latter is a collection of `b`s. The result is then a collection (the same type of collection) of `b`s, by applying every element in the second collection to every function in the first collection.

So for a list it looks like:

```
(<*>) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
(<*>) fs xs = [fi xj | fi <- fs, xj <- xs]
```

A `Maybe` is also some sort of collection: it either contains *no* elements (the `Nothing` case), or *one* element (the `Just x` case with `x` the element). You can thus see a `Maybe` as a collection with "*multiplicity*" 0..1.

In case one of the two operands is a `Nothing` (or both), then the result is a `Nothing` as well, since if there is no function, or no element, there is no "result" of a function application. Only in case both operands are `Just`s (so `Just f` and `Just x`), we can perform function application (so `Just (f x)`):

```
(<*>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
(<*>) (Just f) (Just x) = Just (f x)
(<*>) _ _ = Nothing
```

In this specific case, we can analyze the use:

```
addRecip :: Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
addRecip x y = (fmap (+) (recipMay x)) <*> recipMay y
  where
    recipMay a | a == 0 = Nothing
               | otherwise = Just (1 / a)
```

We thus see two operands: `fmap (+) (RecipMay x)` and `recipMay y`. In case `x` and/or `y` are `0`, then the operands are respectively `Nothing`. Since in that case the corresponding `recipMay` is `Nothing`.

We thus could write it like:

```
addRecip :: Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
addRecip x y | x == 0 = Nothing
             | y == 0 = Nothing
             | otherwise = Just ((1/x) + (1/y))
```

But in the above we thus repeat the `== 0`, and `1/` logic twice.

Comment: "For a list" ..."applying every element in the second collection to every function in the first collection.” The list comprehension is Cartesian, each fs with every xs. Should it be a zip fs xs? Ambiguous.

Comment: @fp_mora: well there exists a type for such kind of `<*>`: the `ZipList` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList :)

Comment: Totally impressive and of great use. TY!

Answer (score 2):

Here the functor is `Maybe`. That `<*>` will return `Nothing` if either argument is `Nothing` (i.e., it involved a division by zero)

```
Nothing <*> _       = Nothing
_       <*> Nothing = Nothing
```

In the remaining case, it just applies the wrapped function:

```
Just f <*> Just x = Just (f x)
```

Also note that

```
fmap (+) (recipMay x) <*> recipMay y
```

is a slightly unusual notation. Usually that's written as

```
(+) <$> recipMay x <*> recipMay y
```

which is completely equivalent, since `fmap` is written as the infix `<$>`, but arguably more readable.

Here, `fmap (+) (recipMay x)` (or `(+) <$> recipMay x`) means

```
if x == 0
then Nothing 
else Just (\a -> 1/x + a)
```

Comment: Why `x==0` will return `Nothing`?

Comment: Because `recipMay` returns `Nothing` in such case, hence `fmap` does the same.